# Deduce supremum of Set A

Tags: real-analysis, axioms, supremum-and-infimum

Define $$Set A=\{1-\frac 1n\ | n \in\ N\}$$
A. Deduce sup A
b. Use the quanitifier definition of supremum to prove your conjecture in part (a).
My attempt at the solution: I believe sup A is 1?

Comment: Your guess is correct.

Comment: but now I have no idea how to do part b

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, the supremum of $A$ is $1$.  My guess is that your quantifier definition is something like the following:

> $\alpha$ is equal to $\sup(A)$ if $\alpha$ is an upper bound of $A$ and if for every $\epsilon>0$, there is an element $a \in A$ such that $\alpha - \epsilon < a$.

If this disagrees with your definition significantly, please say so.

Assuming that this is what you have as your definition, we want to show $1 = \sup (A)$.  So, for an $\epsilon > 0$, we want to find an element $a = 1 - \frac 1n$ (with $n \in \Bbb N$) such that
$$
1 - \epsilon < 1 - \frac 1n
$$
How can I describe a suitable choice of $n$ in terms of $\epsilon$?

Comment: I figured supremum was 1 due to the fact as n gets larger and larger the value of 1/n will get closer and closer to zero

Comment: Well, $\frac 1 \epsilon$ is not necessarily in $\Bbb N$, so that doesn't quite work... but you're nearly there.  You have the right ideas here, and the right reasoning for why $1$ "should" be the supremum.  The challenge, however, is to show that $1$ satisfies the quantifier condition.

Comment: do i start with the equation $\ a =1-\frac1n\\$?

Comment: Your proof should look something like this: "We first note that $1$ is indeed an upper bound for $a$.  Now, consider any $\epsilon > 0$.  We select an $n \in \Bbb N$ satisfying [???]. The element $a = 1 - 1/n \in A$ satisfies $1 - \epsilon < a$.  Thus, we have shown that $1 = \sup(A)$.